# Spring program not being executed

Tags: java, spring

I try to execute my first spring application but I'm getting error. I'm new to spring can you help me out here that would be appreciated. Here are the codes

```
 package com.bam.springexample;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        HelloSpring obj = (HelloSpring)context.getBean("msgid");
        obj.getMessage();
    }

}
```

here is the POJO class.....

```
package com.bam.springexample;

public class HelloSpring {
private String message;

public void getMessage() {
System.out.println("Your Message is "+ message);
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

the beans.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="msgid" class="com.bam.springexmple.HelloSpring">
       <property name="message" value="Hello Bamadeva Its your first Spring Program ."/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

error I'm getting is

```
Jun 16, 2013 10:12:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1608e05: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1608e05]; startup date [Sun Jun 16 10:12:22 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 16, 2013 10:12:22 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:79)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:411)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:338)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:66)
    at com.bam.springexample.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:307)
    ... 12 more
```

Thanks In Advance...

Edited here after I placed the bean.sml into src folder

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:361)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Where have u placed Beans.xml ?

Comment: Dear I have placed in SRC folder. Still saying  see the above edited post. ThankQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beans file `Beans.xml` is not being found. You should place `Beans.xml` in your classpath.

[image]

Just right click on `src` folder in eclipse and click `new` then `other` and create a new xml file. Put all your code of `beans.xml` in that file.

```
 <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.practice.HelloWorld">
   <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
 </bean>
```

I declared the bean as above.

Call the bean as follows.

```
 ApplicationContext context = 
         new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

  HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
```

This works for me. I can get the value of message.

Comment: @Bamadeva  There should have been some minor mistake. Check all spelling of your filenames and where you have called them. Also, try cleaning the project.

Comment: While running this program generates one beans.out.xml why so may I know?

Answer (score 1):

Spring is looking for `Beans.xml` and not finding it *on the class path*.

The file might well be in your current working directory or somewhere else obvious to humans, but it must be on the Java class path for a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to find it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Put Beans.xml inside project Build path. Following are the steps

1. Right click on the project => select **Build path** => select **configure build path**
2. Select Java Build Path => Source => Click on **Included**

[image]

3. Then click on **Add**  and add your Beans.xml
4. Final configuration is like this:

[image]

5. Click on **Finish** and save all changes. Run the project with *ctrl+F11*.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the physical location of the application and place the .xml file

Ex :C:\Workspace\application-name\target\classes